# Running <script> inside specific <div> only

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to run a script within a specific div only. With my current code, the script affects the image outside of the div as well. I'm using this code on wordpress within a html widget and when I insert the script code, it effects the entire page. I only want it to apply the specific html widget. This is also the reason I want to insert the script within a div, as I want to avoid adding the script to the actual web page (if possible).

Any help or work around would be greatly appreicated.

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <script async defer data-pin-hover="true" data-pin-tall="true" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js">
      </script>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/I63emp4.jpg" height="160">
      </div>
      <img src="https://imgur.com/0VWBThm.jpg" height="160">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Scripts are not scoped / limited to the DOM node they are referenced in. You either need to specify the scope of the script inside it (selecting the relevant classes for example) or have a look at webcomponents which is a much deeper topic though.

Comment: @rauberdaniel the OP didn’t make the script. It’s provided by Pinterest. I’m pretty sure they have documented this somewhere

Comment: @evolutionxbox True, I missed that. The documentation on https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/widgets/save/? doesn't mention anything about limiting scope though, so it might not be possible.

Comment: @rauberdaniel I think `data-pin-tall="true"` has something to do with it, but their API docs aren't very helpful